# axis positioning with imshow - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have been trying to add two axes on the same figure, with very specific locations. The problem is that when I add the plot, they seem to have different sizes to what I specified.

Here is an example

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.7])

M = np.random.random([10, 20])
ax.imshow(M)

plt.show()
```

This is the result

[image]

However, when I use `ax.plot()` instead it seems to place the axis at the correct location.

[image]

My feeling is that it has to do with the aspect ratio in `imshow()` but nothing has worked for me so far. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; the `imshow` aspect, which is set to "equal" by default prevents the axes to scale automatically to the position specified. Usually this is desired though, because you want square pixels in an imshow plot.

In order to set the aspect to automatic, use

```
ax.imshow(M, aspect="auto")
```